# How to locate and display a Unicode character in iOS

Tags: ios, unicode

I'm currently using an star/asterisk character to separate syllables in a vocabulary quiz program. But, I would prefer to use a black dot that sits about midway between the top and bottom of the line height.  So, my questions are

1) How do I find the unicode for this character?

edit: from wikipedia, it looks like the character might be "middle dot", U+00B7

2) How do I display it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just escape unicode characters inside NSString like this:

```
NSString *string = @"Hi \u00B7 there!";
```

[Here's the great website](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b7/index.htm) to reference Unicode codes and how to place them inside programming languages (encodings section).

Comment: Thanks - I actually just pasted the "·", but this is good to know.

Comment: Sure you can do that, but it's quite possible that some editors won't display Unicode chars in the source code. It's safer to stick with ASCII chars and escape everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy and paste this " • " or use `option+8`